# SVN log display for commits occurred in a single day

Tags: date, svn, logging

I have tried running svn log command to list the commits occurred in SVN repository for a day.
But after running the below command in the output, i could see first line was previous day's commit.

Is there any way to get the changes happened in a same day. Any explanation on where i did the mistake?

Command I tried:- svn log <\repo-url> -r {2014-06-03T00:00:00}:{2014-06-03T23:59:59}

result shown as below:-
[image: svn_log_changes_for_a_day]![[]]

Comment: Did my answer help you in 2014? Please, upvote and accept it then. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you'll try to read SVN Book ["Revision Specifiers"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html), "Is Subversion a Day Early?" note at least once?!

> Remember that Subversion will find the *most recent revision of the repository* as of the date you give

I.e when you use date-range in log, **first record will be always earlier**, than range-start and you have to skip first record

For SVN 1.8+ and reasonable short range you can use `--search` + `--search-and` options as additional or main filter

Answer (score 0):

As @LazyBadger has already suggested, you can use `--search` and `--search-and` options with Apache Subversion 1.8+ command-line client. These command-line options are described in [Subversion 1.8 Release Notes](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#svn-log-search).

GUI clients such as TortoiseSVN provide you with an interface to do such searches / filtering / grouping / etc. See TortoiseSVN example [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html).